# On MAC OS, if I want to save a file to folder B, but point it to folder A, what should I do?

Tags: macos, mac, symbolic-link, automator, workflow

I'm not sure what title to give to this question, but what I want is: when I save a file to folder A, it will automatically save it to folder B, and delete it from folder A, what should I do to make that happen?

Should I use a workflow? Symbolic link? what would be the most sucessful choice?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Why not just save the file to folder B then? That roundabout workflow doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

### Add an Automator Folder Action workflow

Use Automator to make a Folder Action workflow. Use `Move Finder Items` from `Finder`'s actions. The Folder Action will move files or folders that are moved or saved in folder A to folder B. When you save the workflow, Automator enables the Folder Action for folder A.

[image: Automator workflow]

### Actions for duplicate files or folders

1. When a file is saved to folder A, but a file of the same name exists in folder B, the workflow leaves the duplicate file in folder A. The file in folder B is unchanged.
2. If you check `Replace existing files`, the workflow will replace the file in folder B without asking.

### To remove or disable a Folder Action

If you want to remove a Folder Action or temporarily disable it, select the folder in Finder. Right-click to select `Services` and `Folder Actions Setup...`

[image: Folder Actions Setup]